# Best practice to find source of PHP script termination

Tags: php, apache, debugging

I have a PHP script that grabs a chunk of data from a database, processes it, and then looks to see if there is more data.  This processes runs indefinitely and I run several of these at a time on a single server.

It looks something like:

```
<?php
    while($shouldStillRun)
    {
       // do stuff
    }
    logThatWeExitedLoop();
?>
```

The problem is, after some time, something causes the process to stop running and I haven't been able to debug it and determine the cause.

Here is what I'm using to get information so far:

- **error_log** - Logging all errors, but no errors are shown in the error log.
- **register_shutdown_function** - Registered a custom shutdown function.  This does get called so I know the process isn't being killed by the server, it's being allowed to finish.  *(or at least I assume that is the case with this being called?)*
- **debug_backtrace** - Logged a debug_backtrace() in my custom shutdown function.  This shows only one call and it's my custom shutdown function.
- **Log if reaches the end of script** - Outside of the loop, I have a function that logs that the script exited the loop (and therefore would be reaching the end of the source file normally).  When the script dies randomly, it's not logging this, so whatever kills it, kills it while it's in the middle of processing.

What other debugging methods would you suggest for finding the culprit?

**Note: I should add that this is not an issue with max_execution_time**, which is disabled for these scripts.  The time before being killed is inconsistent.  It could run for 10 seconds or 12 hours before it dies.

---

**Update/Solution**: Thank you all for your suggestions.  By logging the output, I discovered that when a MySql query failed, the script was set to die().  D'oh.  Updated it to log the mysql errors and then terminate.  Got it working now like a charm!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php says "When the timer expires the script will be aborted and as with the above client disconnect case, if a shutdown function has been registered it will be called." so your statement "This does get called so I know the process isn't being killed by the server," is probably false.

Comment: As you've noted, debug_backtrace is useless in a shutdown function, because the shutdown function has a separate call stack from whatever caused it to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, PHP has a variable in the ini file that says how long a script should run. [max-execution-time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Make sure that you are not going over this, or use the set_time_limit() to increase execution time.  Is this program running through a web server or via cli?

**Adding:**  My Bad Experiences with PHP.  Looking through some background scripts I wrote earlier this year.  Sorry, but PHP is a terrible scripting language for doing anything for long lengths of time.  I see that the newer PHP (which we haven't upgraded to) adds the functionality to force the GC to run.  The problem I've been having is from using too much memory because the GC almost never runs to clean up itself.  If you use things that recursively reference themselves, they also will never be freed.

Creating an array of 100,000 items makes memory, but then setting the array to an empty array or splicing it all out, does NOT free it immediately, and doesn't mark it as unused (aka making a new 100,000 element array increases memory).

My personal solution was to write a perl script that ran forever, and system("php my_php.php"); when needed, so that the interpreter would free completely.  I'm currently supporting 5.1.6, this might be fixed in 5.3+ or at the very least, now they have GC commands that you can use to force the GC to cleanup.

Simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

while(1) {
  if( system("php /to/php/script.php") != 0 ) {
    sleep(30);
  }
}
```

then in your php script

```
<?php

// do a single processing block

if( $moreblockstodo ) {
  exit(0);
} else {
  // no? then lets sleep for a bit until we get more
  exit(1);
}

?>
```

Comment: See my note above :)  - The max-execution-time isn't the issue.  The script is started by another a startup script.

This script starts each process by:
exec('php /script/to/run.php > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $output);

(I get the process id so I can track if it's alive later)

Comment: Have you tried logging the output of the script to a log file?

Comment: exec("php /script/to/run.php >/to/log/file.txt 2>&1 & echo $!")

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that.  The script doesn't output anything, but not a bad way to check some tests.

Answer (score 2):

I'd log memory usage of your script. Maybe it acquires too much memory, hits memory limit and dies?

Answer (score 0):

I'd log the state of the function to a file in a few different places in each loop.

You can get the contents of most variables as a string with [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), using the `var_export($varname,true)` form.

You could just log this to a certain file, and keep an eye on it. The latest state of the function before the log ends should provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like whatever is happening is not a standard php error. You should be able to throw your own errors using a try... catch statement that should then be logged. I don't have more details other than that because I'm on my phone away from a pc.

Comment: `try {something();}catch(Exception $e){trigger_error('your error text :'.$e,E_USER_WARNING);}`. The code has to throw an exception for try/catch to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before on one of our projects at work. We have a similar setup - a PHP script checks the DB if there are tasks to be done (such as sending out an email, updating records, processing some data as well). The PHP script has a while loop inside, which is set to

```
while(true) {
    //do something
}
```

After a while, the script will also be killed somehow. I've already tried most of what has been said here like setting max_execution_time, using var_export to log all output, placing a try_catch, making the script output ( php ... > output.txt) etc and we've never been able to find out what the problem is.

I think PHP just isn't built to do background tasks by itself. I know it's not answering your question (how to debug this) but the way we worked this is that we used a cronjob to call the PHP file every 5 minutes. This is similar to Jeremy's answer of using a perl script - it ensures that the interpreter if free after the execution is done.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Linux, try to look into system logs - the process could be killed by the OOM (out-of-memory) killer (unlikely, you'd also see other problems if this was happening), or a segmentation fault (some versions of PHP don't like some versions of extensions, resulting in weird crashes).